# giving 2 possible answers in python

Tags: python

I am just writing a simple quiz game in Python,
I would like to know the way to give 2 possible answers (python 2.7)
eg. 
(variable) `answer = 'California' OR 'california'`
so the variable answer can accommodate the use from the user of the upper or lower 'C'
or even more variables in the answer.
cheers

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> 'california' in ('California', 'california')
True
```

But you should be using `.lower()` first.

```
>>> 'California'.lower() in ('california', 'florida')
True
```

Comment: thanks, how would you write this in the script not the interpreter

Comment: You can write the exact same line in the script that you'd write in the interpreter. In fact, this is almost always true; otherwise, the interpreter wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
answers = ( 'california', 'California' )
user_answer = 'california'
user_answer in answers # returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to lowercase the user's input, and then have all the answers lowercase, like so:

```
useranswer = raw_input()
if useranser.lower() == 'california':
    #yay!
else:
    #awwww...
```

Comment: answer = 'Watson'
print ("Here is a guessing game. You get three tries! ")
print("What is the name of the computer that played on jeopardy?")

response = raw_input()
if response == answer:
   print ("That is right!! ")
else:
   print ("Sorry, Guess agin !")
   response = raw_input()
if response == answer:
   print ("That is right! ")
else:
   print("Sorry one more guess!")
   response = raw_input()
if response == answer:
   print ("That is right! ")
else:
   print("Sorry. No more guesses, The answer is " + answer)